# Why does the beta energy spectrum of $\rm Sr90/Y90$ only show the peak for $\rm Y90$?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, spectroscopy

Im currently working on an experiment where I am investigating the energy distribution spectrum of Strontium-90 and Yttrium-90, which are two beta-minus decays, with the help of a quarter-circle spectrometer for different B values. While doing my measurements I noticed that there is something odd with the graph I got (posted below) and what I expected.

The theory as I understood it, says that Strontium-90 have a final Q-value of 546 keV and Yttrium-90 has 2280 keV, and if we look at the graph it has a single peak at around 1200 and ends at 2300~, like expected for Yttrium-90. But the way it should be portrayed is Strontium-90 having a very high peak around 270~, even though what we see on the graph is practically nothing of that sort? It's like that element completely vanished. Even though it should be the most noticable peak. (which can be seen from the second graph taken from https://www.nature.com/articles/srep38182)

I am really clueless at this point, as there's nothing I can think of at the top of my mind to explain it.
I'd appriciate any help I could get.

[image]

So this ($\uparrow$) would be my graph made from 100 measurements put in Excel and this ($\downarrow$) is the graph published in Nature.

[image: The graph I'm comparing with]

Comment: your y-axis should be "number of particles N(E) per 100s per keV"

Answer (score 2):

The figure in the Nature article is a calculated spectrum, I think, the sum of two distributions with the same area and different Q-values.

Panel (d) in that same figure indicates that the range of the Sr-90 beta particles in solids is only 1.5 mm.

My best guess is that your Sr-90 is embedded or covered by 1 mm or so of stuff and/or that your detector is not sensitive to low-energy betas.